# c# database migration in code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

i have a simple question. Is there a way to apply an own DbMigration class programmatically?
Example:

```
public partial class MyMigration {
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable("TableA", "TableB");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }
}
```

and somewhere...

```
{
    ...
    if (condition) {
        db.Migrate(new MyMigration);
    } else {
        //nothing todo
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `DbMigrator` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Why not just use the condition in the migration? `if(condition) RenameTable("TableA","TableB");`

Comment: Yes. I should. But i need the automatic migration but in some cases i want to migrate manually the database. It's possibile to obtain this kind of behaviour?